# if $x>1$ and $\log_2x,\log_3x,\log_x16$ are in G.P then what is x $=$

Tags: logarithms

if $x>1$ and $\log_2x,\log_3x,\log_x16$ are in Geometric progression then what is x equal to?

Solution:
$(\log_3x)^2=\log_2x\times\log_x16=\log_216=\log_22^4=4$
$\log_3x=2 or x=3^2=9$

so my doubt is how $(\log_3x)^2=\log_2x\times\log_x16$ while the rest i have understood

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but what is G.P supposed to mean?

Comment: geometric progression

Comment: Ah I see. Then that's why the equality holds. ($a^2 r^2 = a \cdot ar^2$ using the [wikipedia notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality comes from the geometric progression:
$$\log_2 x = a, \quad \log_3 x = ar, \quad \log_x 16 = ar^2$$
Thus
$$(\log_3 x)^2 = a^2 r^2 = a \cdot ar^2 = \log_2 x \log_x 16$$

Comment: Thanks for help.is this the only way to find x

Comment: Many paths lead to rome, but this appears to be the easiest way. Another option would be $\frac{\log_x 16}{\log_3 x} = r = \frac{\log_3 x}{\log_2 x}$, but this is basically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the kind of solution you expect, so forgive me if I am off-topic.

I think that things are easy if you go to natural logarithms or just to a common base; doing so and using ALexR notations, you have $$a=\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}$$ $$ar=\frac{\log (x)}{\log (3)}$$ $$ar^2=\frac{\log (16)}{\log (x)}$$ So, using $a \cdot ar^2=a^2r^2=(ar)^2$ $$\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}\times \frac{\log (16)}{\log (x)}=\Big(\frac{\log (x)}{\log (3)}\Big)^2$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a G.P. is characterized by the fact that after the first one, any term in the progression equals the one that preceedes it multiplied by a constant. Thus, a G.P.  looks like

$$a,\,aq,\,aq^2,\,...,\,aq^n,\,aq^{n+1},\ldots$$

Now, it's easy to check that if we take **any** three *successive* terms  $\;a_{n-1},\,a_n,\,a_{n+1}\;$ in a G.P. we have that $\;a_n^2=a_{n-1}a_{n+1}\;$ .

Thus, in your case, as we're given those three *successive* (this is understood without saying, I think) elements in a G.P., you obtain

$$\log^2_3x=\log_2x\cdot\log_x16=4\log_2x\log_x2=4\implies\log_3x=\pm2\implies x=3^{\pm2}=\begin{cases}9\\{}\\\frac19\end{cases}$$